# crear un circulo alrededor de mis imagenes

Tags: css3

me gustaria poder añadir unos circulos alrededor de mis 3 imagenes que yo pueda cambair su tamñado sin que afecte a la imagen.

```
<div class="row aling-items-center">

    <div class=" col-md-4">
    <img src="imagenes/veterinario.png" class="img-fluid fotoiconohouse " alt="Responsive image">
    </div>
    <div class=" col-md-4 ">
    <img src="imagenes/camioneta.png" class="img-fluid fotoiconohouse" alt="Responsive image">
    </div>
    <div class=" col-md-4 ">
    <img src="imagenes/movil.png" class="img-fluid fotoiconohouse" alt="Responsive image">
    </div>


    </div>
```

Comment: Encima o debajo de ellas?

Comment: encima , osea k el circulo rodee la imagen sin distorsionarla , vamso que se ve un circulo alrededorde la imagen y la imagen dentro.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres cambiar la altura o el ancho puedes cambiar `width` y `height` en `.col-md-4`.

Si quieres que la imagen tenga la forma de un círculo, puedes usar `background-image` como el ultimo ejemplo con `imagenCirculo`.

```css
.col-md-4 img {
  max-width: 80%;
  padding: 25% 0;
}

.col-md-4 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.imagenCirculo {
  background-image: url('https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/199/sunflowers-6-1392951.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 150%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row aling-items-center">

  <div class=" col-md-4">
    <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/199/sunflowers-6-1392951.jpg" class="img-fluid fotoiconohouse " alt="Responsive image">
  </div>
  <div class=" col-md-4 ">
    <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/199/sunflowers-6-1392951.jpg" class="img-fluid fotoiconohouse" alt="Responsive image">
  </div>
  <div class=" col-md-4 imagenCirculo">
  </div>


</div>
```